# how should I create a play project having sub-projects

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have just started on a new web-app project. I am confused how I should create the play project for the directory structure. I am only working on web frontend at the moment but I want to be certain that way I create projects evolves as I start working on other modules. Also, as the team grows, I would like to give them access to only their respective module.

The directory structure I want to use is

```
webapp-> top level //this is the git directory as well
webapp/code_related //I plan to keep all code related stuff here eg. guidelines, documentation
webapp/code_related/code  //all code goes here
webapp/code_related/code/backend //all backend code goes here
webapp/code_related/code/frontend //all backend code goes here
webapp/code_related/code/common //all the common code/libraries which both frontend and backend might use goes here
webapp/code_related/code/frontend/web //all code for browsers goes here
webapp/code_related/code/frontend/mobile //all code for mobiles goes here
webapp/code_related/code/frontend/common //all the common code/libraries which both web abd mobile might use goes here
```

1. Shall I create a play project for each of the directories (so each
   directory will have its `build.sbt`?
2. Would I be able to build/compile/test all the directories together and individually?

Comment: So far, I have created a project named `webapp` at location `C:\...\webapp\code_related\code` and a module named `web`. The root content directory for `web` is `webapp/code_related/code/frontend/`. IntelliJ has created `build.sbt` and its default directory structure at `frontend/` location.  The two issues I am already seeing are 1. my `index.html` is at `web/` while IntelliJ expects `html` at `app/views`. 2. I have kept `css`, `js` in `common` while IntelliJ expects them in `public` folder. IntelliJ also has created `.gitignore` but my top level directory and its `.gitignore` is at `webapp`

Comment: shall I change my initial directory structure and use `IntelliJ`'s or shall I change configuration in `IntelliJ` to use my directory structure? I do not know what the best practice would be. If I use IntelliJ's structure then I could be in trouble if I switch to `Ecllise` in future

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I would recommend keeping your project IDE independent - IDE's are intelligent enough to import an existing project structure into them using your `build.sbt`.

I also recommend to have your own front-end (independent of Play) application structure and use the existing build systems for that like `Grunt` or `webpack` or something else depending on your frontend framework and move the compiled (or packaged) frontend code to `play/public` folder and the `routes` file serve them as static resources.

```
yourapp
    frontend
        config
        src
            app
            assets
            index.html
        package.json
        Gruntfile.js
    backend
        conf
        app
        project
        modules
        build.sbt
```

Here is an example from toptal which is using old versions, but you can get some inspiration.

https://github.com/dsinyakov/angularjs-play-blog-app

https://www.toptal.com/java/building-modern-web-applications-with-angularjs-and-play-framework